# Function to return a pointer to the largest number in an array

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

as you can tell by the title I need to write a function that returns a pointer to the largest number in an array, the functions gets a pointer to a double array and it's size. In addition I need to write a main function that will use this function.
Here is the code that I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void BigEl(double* arr, double arrSize);

void BigEl(double* arr, double arrSize)
{
    int i;
    double  maximum, *x;
    maximum = arr[0];
    for (i = 1; i < arrSize; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]>maximum)
        {
            maximum = arr[i];
        }
    }
    *x = maximum;
}
void main()
{
    double myarr[10];
    int i;
    printf("Please insert 10 numbers to the array\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &myarr[i]);
    }
    BigEl(myarr, 10);


}
```

I get this error:

```
Error   1   error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'x' used
```

I don't understand what I did wrong because I did initialized x. 
Any kind of help is appreciated, in addition, tell me if the idea of my code was right because Im not sure if I understood the question correctly.

Comment: You are not returning anything from the function.

Comment: @haccks whilst true, that's not what's generating the compiler error (which is OP's question).

Comment: BTW `"%d"` for `int`

Comment: @abligh; I didn't say that. My comment was in response to the title.

Comment: OT: It's `int main(void)` at least.

Answer (score 4):

You did not initialize the variable `x`. You merely wrote to the the location pointed to by `x`, here:

```
    *x = maximum;
```

when `x` was uninitialized, which is what the compiler is complaining about.

You want something like:

```
double *
BigEl(double* arr, size_t arrSize)
{
    size_t i;
    double *max = arr;
    for (i = 1; i < arrSize; i++)
        if (arr[i] > *max)
            max = &arr[i];
    return max;
}
```

Things I've changed:

1. Use `size_t` for the array size and the counter, not a `double` and an `int`.
2. Retain a pointer to the maximum element, not the maximum element's value.
3. Return the pointer to the maximum element.
4. Remove superflous braces.

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning anything. Also, it might be good to take into consideration the case when the array size is 0. Moreover, the size should be passed as a constant. No other answer has mentioned this.

```
double* BigEl(double* arr, const size_t iSize)
{
    if(iSize == 0)
        return 0;

    double max = arr[0], *x = &arr[0];
    for(unsigned int i=1;i<iSize;++i){
        if(arr[i] > max){
            max = arr[i];
            x = &arr[i];
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: For completeness it should be mentioned that for array indices the type `size_t` is the preferred one. Your code will still fail for negative "sizes".

Answer (score 1):

```
//function that returns a pointer to the largest number
double *BigEl(double* arr, int arrSize)
{
    int i;
    double  *maximum;
    maximum = &arr[0];
    for (i = 1; i < arrSize; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > *maximum)
        {
            maximum = &arr[i];
        }
    }
    return maximum;
}
int main(void)
{
    double myarr[10];
    int i;
    printf("Please insert 10 numbers to the array\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf", &myarr[i]);
    }
    printf("%f\n", *BigEl(myarr, 10));

    return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment to `*x` is incorrect - you are saying "assign to the location pointed to by `x`, without first saying where that is. Aside from that, there are a couple of other issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// return pointer to location from function
double * BigEl(double* arr, double arrSize)
{
    int i;
    // initialise both variables
    double maximum = arr[0], *max_pos = arr;

    for (i = 1; i < arrSize; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]>maximum)
    {
        maximum = arr[i];
        // assign address here
        max_pos = &arr[i];
        }
    }
    // return address
    return max_pos;
}

int main()
{
    double myarr[10];
    double * max_pos;
    int i;
    printf("Please insert 10 numbers to the array\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf", &myarr[i]);
    }
    // use return value here
    max_pos = BigEl(myarr, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to write a function that **returns a pointer** to the largest
>   number in an array

I think you need the follwoing

```
#include <stdio.h>

double * largest_element( const double *a, int n )
{
    const double *largest = a;
    int i;

    for ( i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( *largest < a[i] ) largest = a + i;
    }

    return ( double *)largest;

}

#define N   10

int main(void) 
{
    double a[N];
    int i;

    printf("Please insert %d numbers to the array: ", N );

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        scanf( "%lf", &a[i] );
    }

    printf( "\nThe largest element of the array is %lf\n", *largest_element( a, N ) );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter for example

```
2.2 1.5 5.2 1.8 3.9 5.9 7.7 6.8 2.9 0.8
```

then the program output will be

```
The largest element of the array is 7.700000
```

Comment: @Amnon Hanuhov What do you mean?!

Comment: I enter like 4 numbers and it finishes the scan, it is suppose to scan 10 times, however if I enter integers it scans 10 times. plus it prints a weird number.

Comment: Never mind it works, I did a small mistake that I did not notice.